# Is it correct to say "The prices settle down/up $2 at $100"?

Tags: prepositions, adverbs, phrasal-verbs

```
The prices settle down $2 at $100.
```

or

```
The prices settle up $2 at $100.
```

Are these two words *down* and *up* both adverbs or prepositions?

What is the meaning of *settle* here?

I guess the meaning of first sentence would be

```
$102 --> $100
```

and the meaning of second one would be

```
$98 --> $100.
```

According to the dictionary [OALD *settle*](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/settle_1?q=settle) I look up,

there are some meanings of settle which confuse me.

For example, [8.come to rest] and [9.sink down]

How is the word *settle* used?

**Here are some context:**

> settle up

[Gold futures for June delivery traded mildly lower before turning to *settle up* $6.30 at $1,243.80 an ounce.](http://nbr.com/2016/04/08/stocks-post-worst-week-since-february/)

> settle down

[Even the possibility of production quotas helped crude prices shed most of their declines today and they settle down just 0.2 percent.](http://nbr.com/2016/06/01/transcript-nightly-business-report-june-1-2016/)

Comment: @user3169 In this case, _settle_ is not used as part of these two phrasals. It is used here in the sense of _come to rest._ _Settle up_ has a distinct and different meaning: _to pay a debt._ _Settle down_ also has a distinct and different meaning: _to become quieter._ (_Up_ here is used as an adverb, and not as part of a phrasal, so the OP's conclusions about meaning and usage are correct!)

Comment: Please give us some context. Are you referring to the specialist financial dealing terminology of settlement prices, settle prices etc? Or are you talking about prices varying and stabilising, where we might talk about settle down. I know of no use of **settle up/down** that is quantified as you show.

Comment: @djna It is not possible to interpret _The prices settle down $2 at $100_ as a use of the phrasal verb _settle down._ Clearly, here the verb _settle_ is used in its sense of _come to rest,_ in one case _up_ by 2 dollars, and in the other _down_ by 2 dollars. The ellipsis of _by_ in both sentences is what causes confusion here: _The prices settle down **by** $2 at $100._ Q: "How did the price settle?" A: "Down/up by 2 dollars."

Comment: @P.E.Dent agree it's not **settle down**, I was intending to exclude that possibility. However as written I don't think this is **clear**, not least because it's unusual for more than one price to be down by the same value. Of course your interpretation is reasonable, but as there is also a concept of a **settle price** I need to read this several times to be sure of the intent. Would it not be better to reorder and include a preposition? **The prices settle at $100, down by $2.** and indeed I see you have now suggested the addition of **by**.

Comment: While adding by certainly helps, I'm unconvinced that non-native English speaker will parse your suggestion easily. **The prices settle at $100, down by $2.** is clear. **The prices settle down by $2 at $100** feels clumsy (the by, at combination) and the reader needs to spot that **settle down** is not intended.

Comment: @user9418 The word _exactly_ does not connote "disapproval." Can you tell us why you think it does? (This has nothing to do with your question, of course.)

Comment: @user3169 I have no appetite for a prolonged colloquy on this point, but there is just no way in which _The prices settle up $2 at $100_ could be interpreted as a use of the phrasal. _Settle up_ can take the preposition _with_ or _for,_ but not _by_ and it certainly does not take an amount as its object, since its meaning is "pay in full." We say: _Let's settle up with the waiter,_ or _He settled up for 3 grand._

Comment: @P.E.Dant  Because I read  [You use exactly with a question to show that you disapprove of what the person you are talking to is doing or saying. ](http://dictionary.reverso.net/english-cobuild/exactly), I thought it is inappropriate to use "exactly" in my previous words.

Comment: That is **not** a dictionary. I can create a website, whenever I want to,  that tells you that "up is down," but that would not make it so. When you look for the definition of a word, use a real dictionary like Oxford or Cambridge, or Merriam Webster.

Comment: Yes, The dictionaries I have are physical books such as Oxford, Macmillan and Collins. As I know, the definition [You use exactly with a question to show that you disapprove of what the person you are talking to is doing or saying.] you read on that website is the same as Collins.

Comment: @user9418 One last note on _exactly._ The entry you read at reverso.net should say: _You **can** use exactly with a question to show that you disapprove of what the person...is saying._ For instance: _Exactly what do you think you're doing?_ might connote displeasure. But _Can you tell me **exactly** what this means?_ is perfectly polite. So: _exactly_ in a question does not usually connote displeasure. This is a very subtle point in English, and you should not worry about it at this stage of your learning.

Comment: @P.E.Dant I have not been to North America.

I like the atmosphere about interactions or discussions between Americans 

which give me impression of their willingness to share ideas.

I assume most of users here are living in USA or north america.

Still I like British culture.

That is why I choose Oxford dictionary as one of my primary references for learning English.

Comment: @user9418 We have contributors from all over the world: the U.K., America, Canada, India, and everywhere English is spoken. It's best to consult several dictionaries, though. A convenient way to link to many dictionaries at once is [**here.**](http://www.onelook.com/?w=exactly&ls=a)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A non-native English speaker might easily be misled here by the seeming occurrence of the English phrasal verbs [**settle down**](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/settle-down) and [**settle up.**](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/settle-up)

In these two sentences, neither phrasal is used. Instead, the verb **settle** is used in the sense of *to reach and remain at a certain level or in a certain state.* (See [The Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/settle), which gives the example: *The pound rose slightly against the dollar today, then settled at $1.53.*)

The preposition **by** is elided from both sentences, and including it makes both usages clear:

> The prices settle **down by** $2 at $100.
>   The prices settle **up by** $2 at $100.

The two examples from business journalism which you have included make this usage clear. However, you have set off the two constructions

> settle down

and

> settle up

...as if they are used in their phrasal sense here. Instead, both *up* and *down* are used as *adverbs* here, modifying the verb *settle.*

If the event is described in a Q&A format, the meaning may be easier to understand:

> *Q:*  How did the price settle?
>   *A:*  Down/up by 2 dollars.

Comment: Why do those contexts from nbr.com use settle up/down + [certain amounts of money] instead of settle up/down + **by** + [certain amounts of money]?

Comment: They omit (or elide) the preposition **by** because it is "understood" by the listener to be present. This is called [ellipsis.](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/ellipsis?s=t) See questions about [**_ellipsis._**](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ellipsis)

Comment: Wow, I learn another important concept in linguistics. I never thought about the existence of this case before. Because of words leaved out, I felt confused. Now I feel relaxed.